# c++ 2d dynamic array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

this code read data from file and i want to save it, into 2d dynamic array of objects of type class graph
when i try to check the content of array g of objects its empty ... please help me to save data to the array.

```
class graph
{
public:
    int index;
    int c;
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int s1;
    int s2;
    int t1;
    int t2;
    int weight;
    bool ready;
    graph(int index,int c, int p1, int p2, int s1, int s2,int t1, int t2, int weight,int ready)
    {
        index = index;
        c = c;
        p1 = p1;
        p2 = p2;
        s1 = s1;
        s2 = s2;
        t1 = t1;
        t2 = t2;
        weight = weight;
        ready = ready;
    }

};
```

this is main code

```
int main(){     char argc[20];  int m,index,c,p1,p2,s1,s2,t1,t2,weight,ready;   //graph temp(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);  fstream f;

    cout << "Input file name: "; cin >> argc;       f.open(argc, ios::in);  f >> m;

    graph **g=new graph*[m];        int i = 1;  while (!f.eof())    {

        f >> index >> c >> p1 >> p2 >> s1 >> s2 >> t1 >> t2 >> weight >> ready;         g[i] = new graph(index, c, p1, p2, s1, s2, t1, t2, weight, ready);
            cout<< g[i]->index; 
            i = i + 1;

            } return 0; }
```

Comment: Does this compile without errors?  My understanding is that parameters of a method should have different names than the members of the class (to prevent having to use the `this->` syntax).

Comment: I highly recommend reformatting your `main` function.  Although the compiler doesn't care, anybody wanting to help you will care.

Comment: Make your life easier, use `std::vector` instead of a dynamic array.

Comment: Something tells me your `graph` should be a linked list of `Point` rather than having all those variables in your class.

Comment: This whole thing collapses if `m` is less than the number of entries in the file.  For things like this, either you change your loop to read in up to `m`, or drop doing this and use `std::vector` and `push_back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object initialization problem, simplified:

```
class graph
{
   public:
      int index;
      graph(int index)
      {
         index = index;
      }
};
```

In the above simplified case, the line

```
         index = index;
```

doesn't do anything useful. It is self assignment. The `index` on the LHS is not the member variable. It is the argument. The member variable is still uninitialized.

You can use:

```
      graph(int index)
      {
         this->index = index;
      }
```

Better still, I recommend using:

```
      graph(int index) : index(index) {}
```

Make the change for all your member variables.